# How can I create a plugin installation link?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, nonce

Currently, my code is generating the wrong nonce, I guess.
Here is the code:

```
$action = 'install-plugin';
$plugin = 'akismet';
wp_nonce_url(
    add_query_arg(
        array(
            'action' => $action,
            'plugin' => $plugin
        ),
        admin_url( 'update.php' )
    ),
    $action
);
```

Which generates the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=install-plugin&plugin=akismet&_wpnonce=27ac98eeeb
```

When it should generate (notice the different nonce):

```
http://localhost/WordpressEN/wp-admin/update.php?action=install-plugin&plugin=akismet&_wpnonce=a625535dd6
```

clicking on the first link causes WordPress to throw a 403 forbidden error with the message:

> Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Well, looks like I have found the answer. The action should be changed like so:

```
$action = 'install-plugin';
$slug = 'akismet';
wp_nonce_url(
    add_query_arg(
        array(
            'action' => $action,
            'plugin' => $slug
        ),
        admin_url( 'update.php' )
    ),
    $action.'_'.$slug
);
```

The answer was found in line 275 in the source code: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php